# Is the Complexity Zoo Inclusion Diagram exclusively about classes of decision problems?

Tags: circuit-complexity, circuit-depth

The [Complexity Zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:Q#qnc0) includes the class QNC$^0$, which does not seem to be a class of decision problems. When I chase the references of the link provided, they say

> “To extend this definition from quantum operators to decision problems in the classical sense, we have to choose a measurement protocol, and to what extent we want errors bounded. We will not explore those issues here.”

(https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9804034)

I guess any attempt at making a decision problem version will lead to QNC$^0$ = NC$^0$ since the output of the circuits will only depend on a constant number of bits of the input.

On the other hand, the [zoology introduction](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~greg/zoology/intro.html) states

> Some of the classes in the Zoo are not suitable for this Zoology project because they are not decision classes [...]

Hence the question: Is the Complexity Zoo [Active Inclusion Diagram](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~greg/zoology/diagram.xml) supposed to be about classes of decision problems only?

Comment: Your reasoning sounds correct to me. If you restrict it to decision problems, then QNC^0 = NC^0.

Comment: The complexity zoo has all kinds of classes that complexity theorists care about; for example, [Pcc](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:P#pcc) is a communication complexity class.

On a side note, just because two classes are equal does not imply that they are not interesting. IP=PSPACE but we still study them separately.

Comment: @SankethMenda Thanks, now I've edited the question to be specifically about the Active Inclusion Diagram (which doesn't have Pcc I think)